# How I can split a word without a delimiter and perform operations over the split string in Java 8?

Tags: java, string, java-8, split

This is the code that I have created. I want to Split a word - "UUDDUUDD". I want to perform an operation on every character that I receive from this word. So, I tried using the below code.I'm getting the error as

> error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]

If I'm not using an array i.e **String[] newPath** and just write as **String newPath**, I would not be able to perform iteration operation over the string. Can you help me to know how can I iterate over the new array?

```
for (String[] newPath: path.split(""))
```

```
for (char[] newPath: path.split("")
           {
               if (newPath[i]=="U")
               {
                  count++; 
               }
               else
               {
                  count= count-1; 
               }                
           }
```

Comment: If you want an array of `char`, why not call method [toCharArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--)?

Comment: Think about it this way: What is the return type of split? What is the type of the variable which is used to iterate over each member of a String[]?

Comment: There are many options, did you read the documentation? toCharArray is one, charAt in a for loop is another.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Your edit has changed the code and does not match what the OP is running

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No, it was added in edit 3, which is yours. My edit 2 just removed a couple of tags.

Comment: @tgdavies this is the code that was there from the start. I removed my previous comment since it was incorrect

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `toCharArray()` that's convert `String` into `char[]`.
Remeber for `char` use `'U'` **not** `"U"`.
Here is a correct code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "UUDDUUDD";
    int count = 0;
    
    for (char newPath: path.toCharArray()) {
        if (newPath == 'U') {
            count++;
        } else {
            count--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about doing count— instead?

Comment: Why do you use `++` and not `—` - it’s a little confusing.

Comment: This guy use count - 1, that Im not changed, but you right, I will fixed it.

Comment: You didn’t fix it.

Comment: Yeah sorry, no its ok

Comment: Hi @arch2be, I was using "U" even while verifying with a char. After changing to 'U', it has worked out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Split function returns a String array. In your for loop you should iterate over these values by using a simple String, so newPath is a String, not a String array.
If you want just count 'U' chars in String:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "UUDDUUDD";
        long count = path.chars()
            .filter(ch -> ch == 'U')
            .count();

        System.out.println("number of Us: " + count);
    }
```

Increment count if char is 'U' and decrement otherwise:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "UUDDUUDD";

    long countResult = path.chars()
        .reduce(0, (i, j) -> j == 'U' ? i + 1 : i - 1);

    System.out.println(countResult);
}
```

Comment: This will not generate the correct result since OP counts down when the character is not U.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: " I want to perform an operation on every character". You just filter 'U' character and count it. What if He want to add five to the count on 'D' occurrence?.

Comment: well an example is the code (if/else) in the question

Comment: OK! I missed that, I thought that It's only a count related question.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of String.split() is String[].

So if we are iterating over the result of String.split() we use a String:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String c : "ABCD".split("")) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```